# The ping system doesn't seem to work for me.

Tags: support, comment-replies

In the past week or so I tried pinging other members, but the system doesn't seem to work for me.

Here for example I am writing @Jochen I am trying to ping a member with the handle Jochen, and it doesn't seem to work, here my comment that doesn't seem to present the pinged username of Jochen.
[A claim in Krengel's book on Ergodic Theorems.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1398945/a-claim-in-krengels-book-on-ergodic-theorems)

How to fix this?

Comment: See [Why does @someone sometimes disappear from comments?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6281/why-does-someone-sometimes-disappear-from-comments) (and maybe some of the posts [linked there](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/6281).)

Answer (score 4):

Since the system automatically notifies you on every comment made on *your* post (be it answer or question), you don't have to lose sleep over this. Jochen is being notified of your comments.

In case there is no ambiguity, the system removes @username of the original poster when it occurs at the beginning of the comment. This means that if no one [except you] has left any comments, then the system knows you are pinging the OP and not, possibly, someone else. So the @username is removed.

While we're at it, if you are the only one who left comments under Jochen's answer, and Jochen writes a comment reply to their answer, you will be notified with or without a @username ping.

Comment: Hi, @Asaf. Just thought I'd remind you that "redundant" `@-pings` are only removed if they appear at the _start_ of a comment.

Comment: Right. Thanks, Arthur!